# Who creates xxx-eps-converted-to.pdf and why can't I delete it?

Tags: conversion, pdftops

Consider the following code name `simulator.tex`.

```
% simulator.tex
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{input.tex}
\documentclass[tikz,border=12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[red] (0,0) circle (2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\immediate\write18{pdflatex input}
\immediate\write18{pdftops -f 1 -l 1 -eps input.pdf output.eps}
\foreach \x in {tex,pdf,log,aux}{\immediate\write18{cmd /c del input.\x}}

\begin{document}
I am importing EPS image.\\
\includegraphics{output}
\immediate\write18{cmd /c del output.eps}
\immediate\write18{cmd /c del output-eps-converted-to.pdf}
\end{document}
```

I am using Windows, so some parts of my code above will work only on Windows. Compile the code above with

```
latex -shell-escape simulator
dvips simulator
ps2pdf -dAutoRotatePages=/None simulator.ps
```

And check contents of the folder in which `simulator.tex` exists.

Who creates `output-eps-converted-to.pdf` and why can't I delete it?

Comment: Your MWE does not create `output-eps-converted-to.pdf` unless `simulator.tex` gets processed by `pdflatex`. Then `graphics.cfg` loads package `epstopdf` to convert the EPS image of `\includegraphics{output}` on the fly to a PDF file for pdflatex.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: OK. Thank you. Too many works made me wrongly chose compilers. You can submit it as your answer or I will delete this question shortly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because pdfTeX cannot read EPS files as images, the `graphics` configuration file `graphics.cfg` loads package `epstopdf` (exacter `epstopdf-base`). It uses the shell escape feature to convert EPS files on the fly to PDF files. (It can also be configured to convert other image formats.) The package uses the naming scheme `<original name>-<original extension>-converted-to.<new extension>` to avoid the overwriting of other valuable image files.

Thus it is very likely that you have used `pdflatex` to process `simulator.tex`. Then `\includegraphics{output}` triggers the conversion of `output.eps` to `output-eps-converted-to.pdf`.